Hitman/sniper(?) in Japan(?), more information below
This is my first post so hopefully the information I give is alright.
I'll start of with how I saw it, it was either on live TV or on Netflix (more likely Netflix) - it didn't look too high budget, the setting seemed dark for me.
I don't know any of the actors who was apart of the movie at all to help identify. Unsure of when the movie was released, viewed the movie 1 or 2 years ago.
Parts I kind of remember: (not in order nor 100% positive about)

Sniper/hitman in a tower looking over something (possibly was by a temple)
Japanese girl is either saved or comes to him, not sure which it is, the girl turns out to be a ghost at the end
Sniper/hitman finds out about human trafficking and eventually frees all the girls
For some reason I can't remember they end up in a big house, he asks where the Japanese girl/ghost is and that's when he discovers they was dead
At the very end instead of heading off home he stays so he can be with the ghost

Sorry for the major lack in information regarding this movie, all help is very appreciated.
Unsure if it was based in Japan, all I know is that it's not western and it seemed to be based in Japan/China area

Do you have any clue about the production year of the movie? Do you think it looked more like a recent movie or around 80s, 90s, 2000s?

It's possibly the early 90s, that's the lowest I'd expect it to be
